# Is there anyway to prevent page jumps (from loading images) while scrolling to a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use the following code on page load to smoothly scroll to a div

```
$(document).ready(function() {   

      $('html,body').delay(50).animate({scrollTop:jQuery('#3342').position().top-10}, 'slow'); 

});
```

It works wonderfully to smoothly scroll the page to a predefined div id (in this case `div id=3342`, but the actual div ID changes depending on what button the user clicks).

The problem is that if there are any images in the pages above div 3342, then after the scroll finishes, the page jumps and the entire positioning scroll is for nothing, as that content is no longer on screen.

This is on mobile safari btw.  I know Google chrome has recently introduced Scroll anchoring, and I believe this is the functionality i'm trying to reproduce somehow.

Just FYI, I have no way of knowing the sizes of images or the ratio of the image sizes ahead of time.  They are random images from around the web

Thanks!

EDIT:  I don't want to change to window/load event as that means I would have to wait for all the images to load first, which would delay the scroll event massively on some pages

EDIT:  The image URLs are all on the source page, no ajax loading of pages after the fact

Comment: Change 'document' to 'window'. It won't scroll immediately though.

Comment: @Michael `$(window).ready` is not same as window load event. Will have no different effect

Comment: Depends what  image content source is. Is it in page source or is there ajax content being loaded also?

Comment: @charlietfl the image content is in the page source itself, no ajax loading of images at all.  Thanks

Comment: `ready` event occurs before images are loaded .... window load event occurs after they are loaded when they exist in the original source html

Comment: can adjust scroll in both events if needed

Answer (score 0):

Repeat until complete:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   

  var div = jQuery('#3342');
  var complete = false;
  function adjust () {
    if (!complete) {
      $('html,body').delay(50).animate({scrollTop:div.position().top-10}, 'slow', adjust);
    } else {
      $('html,body').delay(50).animate({scrollTop:div.position().top-10}, 'slow');
    }
  }
  adjust();

  $(window).on('load', function () {
    complete = true;
  });


});
```

Comment: much simpler to just swap `$(document).ready` for `$(window).on('load'`. The rest just overcomplicates it